# CRM 2011 Unknown Condition Operator: NotOn

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm doing this simple query inside a plugin:

```c#
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression(hb_aula.EntityLogicalName);
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

query.Criteria = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
query.Criteria.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression("hb_datafim", ConditionOperator.NotOn, DateTime.Now));

EntityCollection ent = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

Where I'm trying to retrieve all `hb_aula` records in which `hb_datafim` date field is not on today (or some other specific date, `DateTime.Now` is just an example).

When I execute this I get the error

> Unknown Condition Operator: NotOn.

Am I doing anything wrong or is this an unfinished CRM 2011 feature?

Comment: Why not just use a less then 00:00 this morning (so convert DateTime.Now to date only at 00:00 and use that)?

Comment: It looks good to me.  Are you getting the error any ru. Time or compile time?

Comment: AdamV I'm not looking for workarounds I want to know why I can't use that specific operator. If it can't be used why is it there? And to simulate the same operator I would need always two conditions one for less than and other for greater than, and would still have the time part issues.Daryl I get the error at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing around your use case and got the same result.  It looks like this was possibly unfinished in the SDK.  I'd recommend using the following workaround -

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);
DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.Or);
filter.AddCondition("createdon", ConditionOperator.OnOrBefore, yesterday);
filter.AddCondition("createdon", ConditionOperator.OnOrAfter, tomorrow);
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("contact")
    {
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
        Criteria = filter
    };

EntityCollection ent = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```